# How to pass email address parameter in class method call?

Tags: c#

In trying to pass email addresses as parameters to a class method I am getting an error. The error is: Cannot convert string to system.net mail.mailaddress. Can someone explain my issue?

Method Call

```
var fromAddress = "email1@noname.com";
var toAddress = "email2@noname.com;email3@noname.com";
SendEmail _sendEmail = new SendEmail();
_sendEmail.SendMail(fromAddress, toAddress);
```

Class Method

```
public class SendEmail
    {
        public void SendMail(MailAddress fromAddress, MailAddress toAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

                mail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
                mail.To.Add("toAddress");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";

                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                string htmlBody;

                htmlBody = "Write some HTML code here";

                mail.Body = htmlBody;

                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do as follows:

```
var fromAddress =  new MailAddress("email1@noname.com");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("email2@noname.com");

SendEmail _sendEmail = new SendEmail();
_sendEmail.SendMail(fromAddress, toAddress);
```

Or change the method parameters type  from `MailAddress` to `string`

```
public void SendMail(string fromAddress, string toAddress)
{
}
```

Don't do the both at same time please! Then you will face similar problem again.

Moreover in your `SendMail()` method change `mail.To.Add("toAddress");` line to `mail.To.Add(toAddress);` if `toAddress` passing MailAddress type or `mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));` if passing as string type.

If your `toAddress` contain multiple addresses separated by comma then use method parameter as string and in stead of `mail.To.Add(toAddress);` line do as follows:

```
foreach(string emailTo in toAddress.Split(';'))
{
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailTo));
}
```

Comment: @SGekko Please check my updated answer. You have problem in `mail.To.Add("toAddress");` this line.

Comment: It is an honor if your answers are copied

Comment: @Steve Sorry! did not that! I notice this later from the queston. One more thing your answer still have problem in `mail.To.Add(s);` it should be `mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(s));` . Please remove down vote. Humble request.

Comment: That's not true. You can pass a string to mail.To.Add and your first example will not work because you cannot build an MailAddress with another MailAddress. And about copying. You have changed your answer two times after I have made the changes in mine. I give you the benefit of doubt but it is really a weird coincidence

Comment: Okay! Let me check in my side. I always ready to take the truth. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve Did not understand `you cannot build an MailAddress with another MailAddress.` that line.

Comment: @Steve You may be did not notice this line : `Don't do the both at same time please! Then you will face similar problem again.`

Comment: Inside the SendMail the OP uses _mail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress)_ If you pass an MailAddress as parameter the new will fail. So your first example will not be compilable if you don't change also SendMail

Comment: Okay! I shall check more details later. But complied successfully. Are you saying it will fail in run time.?

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear. The SendMail method expects two MailAddress and you pass two strings. Besides, inside the SendMail you work on these two parameters like they were strings. So just change the signature of the SendMail method to receive two strings

```
public class SendEmail
{
    public void SendMail(string fromAddress, string toAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
            // Note also the error on this line. 
            // You should put each single address in the To field, 
            // not all together
            foreach(string s in toAddress.Split(';'))
               mail.To.Add(s);
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string htmlBody;

            htmlBody = "Write some HTML code here";

            mail.Body = htmlBody;

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, note that you can't put multiple addresses on the mail.To.Add method. You need to put them one by one and thus you need a loop splitting the input string in the single mail addresses to add